# how to resolve Hard drive location could not be displayed error in ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.10

I face this error when I open my external hard drive in ubuntu 22.10
I checked all the media there is no such file with this name inside my hard drive.
how can I resolve this issue?

[image]